# Python program to print area and perimeter of rectangle If user type 1 area is displayed If user type 2 perimeter is displayed

Tags: python

Python Program to find Area of a Rectangle

I am beginner need your help if i use switch case as per requirement also see in pics.

```
width = float(input('Please Enter the Width of a Rectangle: '))
height = float(input('Please Enter the Height of a Rectangle: '))

# calculate the area
Area = width * height

# calculate the Perimeter
Perimeter = 2 * (width + height)

print("\n Area of a Rectangle is: %.2f" %Area)
print(" Perimeter of Rectangle is: %.2f" %Perimeter)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Python has no switch case. You can use if-elif-else ?

```
width = float(input('Please Enter the Width of a Rectangle: '))
height = float(input('Please Enter the Height of a Rectangle: '))
# calculate the area
Area = width * height

# calculate the Perimeter
Perimeter = 2 * (width + height)

AreaOrPerimeter = int(input('1:Area / 2:Perimeter: '))

if AreaOrPerimeter == 1:
    print("\n Area of a Rectangle is: %.2f" % Area)
elif AreaOrPerimeter == 2:
    print(" Perimeter of Rectangle is: %.2f" % Perimeter)
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I thought some thing like this def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        0: "zero", 
        1: "one", 
        2: "two", 
    }

Comment: switcher = { 
                1: "area", 
        2: "perimeter", 
    }

Comment: I want autodownload a outlook attached file on daily basis from specific sub-line in document folder&it should be copy from document folder to linux remote server-A via winscp and file will be move to from A server to server B in /root